# Save form data and store as a csv file

Tags: php, forms, csv

I am trying to code a PHP file into my website. I have a form, created in HTML, that has the fields First Name, Last Name, and Phone Number. I would like to have those 3 fields saved and stored in a csv file when the user clicks the submit button, and if it passes all the validation, of course. However, my code doesn't seem to be storing any data entered, for some reason.

Here is the HTML code:

```
   <?php include 'php/form.php',;?>

    <div class="formme">
      <form action="php/form.php">
       <div class="form-1">
            <div class="col-1">
                <label for="fname" class="fname">First name</label>
            </div>
          <div class="ph-1">
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-2">
          <div class="col-2">
            <label for="lname" class="lname">Last name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="ph-2">
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-3">
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="lname" class="tel">Phone number</label>
          </div>
          <div class="ph-3">
            <input type="tel" id="telNo" name="telNo" placeholder="Your phone number...">
          </div>
        </div>

      <div class="btn">
          <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </form>
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

//Store form data in date.csv 
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

//collect form data
$fname = isset( $_POST['fname'] ) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
$lname = isset( $_POST['lname'] ) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
$phone = isset( $_POST['telNo'] ) ? $_POST['telNo'] : '';

//check name is set
if ( $fname == '' ) {
    $error[] = 'First name is required';
}

if ( $lname == '' ) {
    $error[] = 'Last name is required';
}

//check for a valid phone number
$pattern = '/^(?:\(\+?44\)\s?|\+?44 ?)?(?:0|\(0\))?\s?(?:(?:1\d{3}|7[1-9]\d{2}|20\s?[78])\s?\d\s?\d{2}[ -]?\d{3}|2\d{2}\s?\d{3}[ -]?\d{4})$/';
if ( ! preg_match( $pattern, $phone ) ) {
    $error[] = 'Please enter a valid phone number';
}


//if no errors carry on
if ( ! $errors ) {
    # Title of the CSV
    $header = "FName,LName,Phone\n";
    //set the data of the CSV
    $data = "$fname,$lname,$phone\n";

    # set the file name and create CSV file
    $FileName = __DIR__ . "/formdata-" . date( "d-m-y-h-i-s" ) . ".csv";
    if ( file_exists( __DIR__ . $FileName ) ) {
        //we only need header once
        file_put_contents( $FileName, $data, FILE_APPEND );
    } else {
        //add csv header
        file_put_contents( $FileName, $header . $data );
    }

}

$error_message = '';
//if their are errors display them
if ( $errors ) {
foreach ( $errors as $error ) {
    $error_message .= "<p style='color:#ff0000'>$error</p>";
}
}
```

Comment: have you allready checked, if `$errors` is false?

Comment: `$errors` is not defined at all?

Comment: I suppose not. How would I define it? (I'm just a designer, the developer wrote this code and I'm just trying to fix it while he's occupied with other work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found errors and suggestions:

- After `include 'php/form.php'` you had a comma which didn't belong there and throwed the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in [....].php on line 1`.
- Rename "form.php" to "create-csv.php" because it's a more intention revealing name. Read [Clean, high quality code](https://www.butterfly.com.au/blog/website-development/clean-high-quality-code-a-guide-on-how-to-become-a-better-programmer).
- Change the submitting strategy: Let's say that the file containing the html form is named "index.php". Then make the form's action to be an empy string, by setting `action=""`. This means that the form will be submitted to the page in which it resides, e.g. to "index.php". This way, because you are including "create-csv.php" into "index.php", you will be able to access all variables from the scope of "create-csv.php" inside the "index.php" too. For example, you will be able to access `$errors` array (defined and filled in "create-csv.php") in the "index.php".
- The form's method must be POST. So, in the form's action, set the attribute `method="post"`. Always set a method attribute in the form tags.
- You missed the closing } for the `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` statement.
- The Submit button must contain `name="submit"` attribute in order to be recognized by the `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` statement.
- You had `$errors`, but also `$error`. Make it `$errors`, since the array holds multiple error items. Pay attention to details. Especially the ones regarding variable, function names.
- Don't print html code from php code. Display the errors in a div container (of css class "errors") in the html code directly.
- In the input for the first name: replace `name="firstname"` with `name="fname"`.
- In the input for the last name: replace `name="lastname"` with `name="lname"`.
- In the label for the phone: replace `for="lname"` with `for="telNo"`.
- In order to check if there are any errors, you must check for the existence of `$errors`. So, instead of using `if ($errors) {...}`, use `if (isset($errors)) {...}`. With `if ($errors) {...}` you are just checking for emptiness.
- Don't use "#" for the PHP comments, but "//" for single lines and /* ... */ for multiple-line-comments.
- Replace `$FileName` with `$fileName`. Use this "camelCase" naming convention for variable and function names in PHP code.
- Replace `if (file_exists(__DIR__ . $fileName)) {...}` with `if (file_exists($fileName)) {...}` because `__DIR__` is already preppended to the variable `$fileName`.

Below is a working code. Search for the string "@todo" in it and act correspondingly. There is just one actually, in "create-csv.php".

Note that I didn't test with a proper phone number, because I don't have time to decode the phone number format that you are using. Give a hint to the user (like me) with how the number should look like.

Good luck.

#### index.php:

```
<?php
/*
 * ================
 * Error reporting.
 * ================
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 0); // SET IT TO 0 ON A LIVE SERVER !!!

/*
 * ==================================================================
 * Execute operations upon form submit (store form data in date.csv).
 * ==================================================================
 */
include 'php/create-csv.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="formme">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <?php
                /*
                 * Display all errors if any.
                 */
                if (isset($errors)) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="errors">
                        <?php
                        foreach ($errors as $error) {
                            ?>
                            <p style="color:#ff0000">
                                <?php echo $error; ?>
                            </p>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>

                <div class="form-1">
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <label for="fname" class="fname">First name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ph-1">
                        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Your name..">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-2">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <label for="lname" class="lname">Last name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ph-2">
                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Your last name..">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-3">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label for="telNo" class="tel">Phone number</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ph-3">
                        <input type="tel" id="telNo" name="telNo" placeholder="Your phone number...">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="btn">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### create-csv.php (inside folder "php"):

```
<?php

/*
 * ==================================================================
 * Execute operations upon form submit (store form data in date.csv).
 * ==================================================================
 */
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Collect the form data.
    $fname = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
    $lname = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
    $phone = isset($_POST['telNo']) ? $_POST['telNo'] : '';

    // Check if first name is set.
    if ($fname == '') {
        $errors[] = 'First name is required';
    }

    // Check if last name is set.
    if ($lname == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Last name is required';
    }

    // Validate the phone number.
    $pattern = '/^(?:\(\+?44\)\s?|\+?44 ?)?(?:0|\(0\))?\s?(?:(?:1\d{3}|7[1-9]\d{2}|20\s?[78])\s?\d\s?\d{2}[ -]?\d{3}|2\d{2}\s?\d{3}[ -]?\d{4})$/';
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $phone)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid phone number';
    }

    // If no errors carry on.
    if (!isset($errors)) {
        // The header row of the CSV.
        $header = "FName,LName,Phone\n";
        // The data of the CSV.
        $data = "$fname,$lname,$phone\n";

        /*
         * The file name of the CSV.
         * 
         * NB: __DIR__ describes the location in which this file resides.
         * To go up one level use "dirname(__DIR__)".
         * 
         * NB: You will not be able to append data to an existing file if you use time components 
         * (hour, minutes, seconds) inside the file name. Imagine that you are creating a file 
         * right now, at 12:18:43 o'clock. Then the file will be named "formdata-09-01-18-12-38-43.csv".
         * One second later you will not be able to append data to it because the time will be "12:38:44".
         * Then a new file "formdata-09-01-18-12-38-44.csv" will be created.
         * 
         * I suggest using only the date whithout the time in the file name.
         * 
         * @todo Read the comment above!
         */
        $fileName = dirname(__DIR__) . "/formdata-" . date("d-m-y-h-i-s") . ".csv";

        /*
         * Create the CSV file.
         * If file exists, append the data to it. Otherwise create the file.
         */
        if (file_exists($fileName)) {
            // Add only data. The header is already added in the existing file.
            file_put_contents($fileName, $data, FILE_APPEND);
        } else {
            // Add CSV header and data.
            file_put_contents($fileName, $header . $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to include the file 'php/form.php'. You dont capture the data because you did not specify the method in your form. Just change your form to

`<form action="php/form.php" method="post">`

and your good to go.